# I removed a repo on web page, but the repo still in Github window

Tags: github

I want to rebuild a repo, so I removed it and create it again, but I got this message "Name already exists on this account". I found that this repo was still in Github window(Github client) and I still can user it, but I can't view it on github, the web page show "404 This is not the web page you are looking for" to me.
How can I completely remove this repo? thanks.